# Return results that dont have specific property

Tags: sparql

I am trying to use FILTER to retrieve pages that don't have a specific property.

I am getting all the links from the `dbo:wikiPageWikiLink` property of that [page](https://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece). I want to keep only the links that don't have the `dbp:carbs` property. Below is my query that from what I have read from previous questions it returns anything that isn't `dbp:carbs`.

```
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/>

SELECT ?link
WHERE {
  ?link dbo:wikiPageWikiLink <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece> .
  ?link ?p ?o
  FILTER(?p != dbp:carbs) .
}
```

Comment: for future reference, the specs are a good start: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation - the reason why `FILTER(?p != dbp:carbs)` doesn't work is basically because it only looks if there is any triple where the predicate is not `dbp:carbs` which all of the entities trivially fulfill, especially as you already asked for only entities that have a `dbo:wikiPageWikiLink` and maybe confusing for you, but that triple already is a valid solution aka binding for the second triple pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`FILTER NOT EXISTS`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#neg-notexists), you get all entities that don’t have the specified triple pattern(s):

```
SELECT ?link
WHERE {

  ?link dbo:wikiPageWikiLink <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Grape_varieties_of_Greece> .
  
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?link dbp:carbs [] . }

}
```